# How to use ANY operator with array field with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How to find all posts with a tag 'apple' ?

```
  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string
    field :tags, {:array, :string}

    timestamps()
  end
```

With postgresql it would be:

`SELECT title FROM posts WHERE 'apple' = ANY(tags);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use Ecto's [in/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#in/2) operator. The second example for that function is exactly what you want.

```
MyApp.Repo.all(from post in MyApp.Posts, where: ^"apple" in post.tags)
```